# JQuery Animation Flickers after switching programs/tabs

Tags: jquery, animation, setinterval, flicker, worker

OK, so I am creating a simple counter that counts up from a set number, I know there are certain restraints if the counter reaches 9999 for example, but I don't really care about these as the user will not be on the page for that long.

What I do care about is a flickering issue which I am having, whereby if you switch tabs or switch programs on the OS and return to the browser, the numbers will be flickering.

For an example, just try out the fiddle below and try alt+tab to another program for 10 secs then return and you should see the flickering.

http://jsfiddle.net/4KPGh/

Thanks in advance to anyone who can enlighten me as to what is causing this! As you can see from the code, I already used a WebWorker for the timer, as I read that using a set interval within this webworker would work even as a background task when switching tabs, but am still having issues.

The Code:

```
var currentDigit = 5;


// makeWebWorker is a little wrapper for generating a web worker to handle timing and destroying it.
function makeWebWorker(script) {
    var URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
        Blob = window.Blob,
        Worker = window.Worker;

    if (!URL || !Blob || !Worker || !script) {
        return null;
    }

    var blob = new Blob([script]),
        worker = new Worker(URL.createObjectURL(blob));

    return worker;
}

function setupCountTimer() {
    var timerCode = "self.addEventListener('message', function(e) { var data = e.data;var date = new Date();console.log(date);if (data.cmd=='start') {postMessage(data.msg);setInterval(function(){postMessage('message');},850)}} ,false);";

    // CREATE TIMER (To run within web worker)
    if(!_bgTimer) {
        var _bgTimer = makeWebWorker(timerCode);

        _bgTimer.postMessage({'cmd':'start'});

        _bgTimer.onmessage = function(e) {
            count();
        };
    }
}

function incrementNumber(digit, value) {
    var el = $('.numbers p:nth-child(' + digit + ')'), // Element
        newValue = value + 1;

    el.animate({
        marginTop: "-150px"
    }, 200, "swing", function() {
        el.text(newValue);
        el.animate({
            marginTop: "150px"
        }, 0, function() {
            el.animate({
                marginTop: "0px"
            }, 200, "swing");
        });
    });
}

function checkThirdNumber() {
    var nextDigit = currentDigit - 2,
        nextEl = $('.numbers p:nth-child(' + nextDigit + ')'), // Element
        nextValue = parseInt(nextEl.text());
    if (nextValue < 9) {
        currentDigit = nextDigit;
        incrementNumber(currentDigit, nextValue);
        currentDigit = nextDigit + 2;
    } else {
        incrementNumber(nextDigit, - 1);
        checkFourthNumber();
    }
}

function checkFourthNumber() {
    var nextDigit = currentDigit - 2,
        nextEl = $('.numbers p:nth-child(' + nextDigit + ')'), // Element
        nextValue = parseInt(nextEl.text());
    if (nextValue < 9) {
        currentDigit = nextDigit;
        incrementNumber(currentDigit, nextValue);
        currentDigit = nextDigit + 2;
    } else {
        incrementNumber(nextDigit, - 1);
    }
}

function checkNextNumber() {
    var nextDigit = currentDigit - 1,
        nextEl = $('.numbers p:nth-child(' + nextDigit + ')'), // Element
        nextValue = parseInt(nextEl.text());
    if (nextValue < 9) {
        currentDigit = nextDigit;
        incrementNumber(currentDigit, nextValue);
        currentDigit = nextDigit + 1;
    } else {
        incrementNumber(nextDigit, - 1);
        checkThirdNumber();
    }
}

function count() {
    var el = $('.numbers p:nth-child(' + currentDigit + ')'), // Element
        currentValue = parseInt(el.text()); // Element value
    if (currentValue < 9) {
        incrementNumber(currentDigit, currentValue);
    } else if (currentDigit >= 2 && currentDigit < 6) {
        incrementNumber(currentDigit, - 1);
        checkNextNumber();
    } else {
        currentDigit = 0;
    }
}
setupCountTimer();
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone interested, I managed to mostly solve this problem, by using the jQuery promise function to run all of the animations sequentially. The function that does this is 'runAnimations' below and the updated version of my function 'incrementNumber' that works with this is also listed below for anyone interested...

```
// Run animations sequentially using jQuery promise
var runAnimations = function(functionArray){
    var func = functionArray.splice(0,1);
    func[0]().promise().done(function(){
        if(functionArray.length > 0 ) {
            runAnimations(functionArray);
        }
    });
}

function incrementNumber(digit, value) {
    var $el = $('.numbers p:nth-child(' + digit + ')'), // Element
        newValue = value + 1;

        // Animate current number out
        numberOut = function() {
            $el.animate({marginTop: "-150px"}, 200, "swing");
            return $el;
        };

        // Setup the next number
        setNextNumber = function() {
            $el.text(newValue);
            $el.css({marginTop: "150px"});
            return $el;
        };

        // Animate next number in
        numberIn = function() {
            $el.animate({marginTop: "0px"}, 200, "swing");
            return $el;
        };

        runAnimations([numberOut,setNextNumber,numberIn]);
}
```